# Xamarin Image Grid from Folder

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to display an Image Grid with Text. Using Images from a Folder. I have tries various approaches and tutorials with no success. I have both READ and WRITE permissions for the Internal and External Storage. Whenever I debug the application all I get is a blank screen. I have tried setting a breakpoint on the Adapters GetView() method which never gets hit.

Here is my MainActivity OnCreate() method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    if (!_dir.Exists()) { _dir.Mkdir(); }

    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(R.Layout.Main);

    string[] FilePath = null;
    string[] FileName = null;

    if (_dir.IsDirectory)
    {
        DroidIO.File[] imageList = _dir.ListFiles();
        FilePath = new string[imageList.Length];
        FileName = new string[imageList.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Length; i++)
        {
            FilePath[i] = imageList[i].AbsolutePath;
            FileName[i] = imageList[i].Name;
        }
    }

    var gvImageList = FindViewById<GridView>(R.Id.gvImageList);
    gvImageList.SetAdapter(new ImagesFromFolderAdapter(this, FilePath, FileName));
    gvImageList.ItemClick += delegate { gvImageList_ItemClick(); };
}
```

And my Image Adapter Class:

```
public class ImagesFromFolderAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity context;
    private string[] filePath;
    private string[] fileName;

    public  ImagesFromFolderAdapter(Activity c, string[] fp, string[] fn)
    {
        this.context = c;
        this.fileName = fn;
        this.filePath = fp;
    }

    public override int Count { get; }

    public int GetCount()
    {
        return filePath.Length;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(R.Layout.gallery_item_layout, null);

        view.FindViewById<ImageView>(R.Id.gitemImage).SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(filePath[position]));
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(R.Id.gitemText).Text = fileName[position];

        return view;

    }
}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I am currently using an LG G3 as a debug device if this helps. Thankyou for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You returned a zero count for your grid adapter.

Change

`public override int Count { get; }`

To

```
 public override int Count
 {
      get { return filePath.Length; }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I missed that!